# multiple html file upload controls on android

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have a web page that needs to work in IE as well as mobiles. On the page I have 4 file uploads. To make the page look modern it posts to an iframe handler. My problem is that on android it only uploads the first file and ignores the last. My code is below

```
try {
    $('#BtnUpload').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner  fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i> Uploading');
    action_url = 'uploader.aspx';
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("id", "upload_iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("name", "upload_iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("width", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("height", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("border", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("style", "width: 0; height: 0; border: none;");
    // Add to document...
    form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);
    window.frames['upload_iframe'].name = "upload_iframe";

    iframeId = document.getElementById("upload_iframe");

    // Add event...
    var eventHandler = function() {

        if (iframeId.detachEvent) iframeId.detachEvent("onload", eventHandler);
        else iframeId.removeEventListener("load", eventHandler, false);

        // Message from server...
        if (iframeId.contentDocument) {
            content = iframeId.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
        } else if (iframeId.contentWindow) {
            content = iframeId.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
        } else if (iframeId.document) {
            content = iframeId.document.body.innerHTML;
        }
        var imagesUpdate = content.split(',');
        for (var x in imagesUpdate) {
            var keyval = imagesUpdate[x].split(':');
            currentuploads[keyval[0]] = keyval[1];
            //console.log(keyval[1]);
        }
        $('#BtnUpload').html('Upload documents');
        hideShowImages();

        // Del the iframe...
        try {
            setTimeout(function() {
                //iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById(iframeId))
                $("#upload_iframe").remove();
                //document.getElementById("upload_iframe").removeChild(document.getElementById("upload_iframe"));
            }, 250);
        } catch (e) {}
    }

    if (iframeId.addEventListener) iframeId.addEventListener("load", eventHandler, true);
    if (iframeId.attachEvent) iframeId.attachEvent("onload", eventHandler);

    // Set properties of form...
    form.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe");
    form.setAttribute("action", action_url);
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
    form.setAttribute("encoding", "multipart/form-data");

    // Submit the form...
    form.submit();
} catch (e) {
    var err = e.message;
    var isIE10 = false;
    /*@cc_on
        if (/^10/.test(@_jscript_version)) {
            isIE10 = true;
        }
    @*/
    if (err.substring(0, 16) == 'Access is denied' && isIE10) {
        $('#BtnUpload').click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake, the max file upload and file size were not set in the web.config. all working now